# How to make config section configurable

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

We started exploring WSO2 DSS with Cassandra, but didn't find a way to make config section configurable so that this section can be independent of the environment.

```
<data name="TestDs" transports="http https local">
    <config id="CassandraDS">
        <property name="cassandraServers">0.0.0.0,0.0.0.0,0.0.0.0</property>
        <property name="keyspace">test</property>
        <property name="port">9042</property>
        <property name="username">XXXX</property>
        <property name="password">XXXXX</property>
        <property name="dataCenter">XX</property>
        <property name="consistencyLevel">LOCAL_QUORUM</property>
    </config>           
</data>
```

Is there a way to make it configurable ?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to define the datasource outside the service?

Comment: Yes, would like to create above section outside and link it with individual data files.